# Does reputation in one community affect reputation in other communities?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

I started using Stack Exchange not long ago. I noticed that the initial community I joined I quickly lost the ability to ask questions. In other communities I had no trouble and am using regularly. Maybe it was my initial lack of knowledge in using the system that got me banned in one community (in terms of asking questions). My question is: Does my reputation in other communities in any way help or not in a community where I cannot ask questions?

Comment: Related: [What can I do when getting "We're no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are asking the following:

Can participation in other Stack Exchange sites affect a question (or answer) ban on another specific site?

The answer to that is: No.

In order to get out of a question (or answer) ban on a site, you need to positively participate on that site by giving good answers, asking good questions, and/or providing good suggested edits to posts.

Comment: What would be considered positive participation?

Comment: Giving good answers, asking good questions, providing good suggested edits to posts.

Comment: I am not able to ask, answer, comment, edit.  In fact the only option I saw I have left is just to read what's there.

Comment: "... providing good suggested edits to posts.". You can still do that. And once you have 50 rep, you will be able to comment everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Not for the most part - the reputation (and subsequent privileges) apply to the individual site only.

The only times that one site's reputation affects other ones that you are a member of is when one reaches 200 rep for the first time, in which case you'll receive a +100 rep Association Bonus on all of your other sites that you are a member of.